# Removing buttons from a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a UIScrollVIew using IB. Then using the following code i add a few buttons to this UIScrollView.

```
for (int index=0; index<3;index++)
{
    UIButton* button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(18,200,300,45)];
    [button setTag:100+index];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(butclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
}
```

Now i need a way to remove these buttons which i added from the ScrollView.

note: There are other buttons, images, labels attached to the UIScrollView. And those should not be removed. It's only the buttons that i added programatically should get removed from the UIScrollView.

Comment: I would accept @Antonio's solution, but if you're unsure about how many buttons were added earlier, run his loop up to the max number that could be there.  In some cases then, viewWithTag will turn up nil, but there's no harm in sending [nil removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a tag on those buttons, then you can take them again using:

```
for (int index=0; index<3;index++)
{
    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:100+i];
    [myButton removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Or save those buttons in an array, and then you can do the same.

And if you just want to hide them, you can do:

```
myButton.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I was typing the same thing, but wondering how the viewWithTag answers all the added buttons.  Was about to suggest a range of tags for the buttons to be removed.  Would he need to call this in a loop (to get all of them)?

Comment: I have edited the question by adding the TAG property. The number of buttons i am adding above could change (it could be 2, 5, 7 or 10). How could i know the tags of each of those buttons in order to remove it ?

Comment: The array idea works, but sounds kind of awful.  One other thing:  my bet is the questioner has some app condition that makes him want the buttons to be hidden and re-shown, not removed and reallocated.  Doesn't solve the tag question, but it sure would be prettier to just hide them.

Comment: Yeah.  Better, but now, if he needs an arbitrary number of them, the edit would be to "search", by counting up to the max number he might have added earlier, then removing if the viewWithTag turns up a subview.